# Route not recognised in MVC 4 WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I haven't used the ASP.NET WebAPI much although I have used routes in straight MVC. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, perhaps someone can help?
I have one controller called UsersController and two methods on it, Register and Details, both take two string parameters and return a string, both marked as HttpGet.
Originally I started with two route mappings in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "TestApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{key}"
  );
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "Test2Api",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{class}"
  );
```

With this set up only the first route is found for a URL such as:

```
http://<domain>/api/users/register/a123/b456/
```

If I call:

```
http://<domain>/api/users/details/a123/b456/
```

I get a 404. If I swap the two routes around then I can call the Details method but not the Register method, again getting a 404. The workaround I have in place is to be more specific with the routes:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "TestApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/register/{userId}/{key}"
  );
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "Test2Api",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/details/{userId}/{class}/"
  );
```

The UsersController looks like:

```
namespace HelloWebAPI.Controllers
{
  using System;
  using System.Web.Http;
  using HelloWebAPI.Models;

    public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
      [HttpGet]
      public string Register(string userId, string key)
      {
        return userId + "-" + key;
      }

      [HttpGet]
      public string Enrolments(string userId, string @class)
      {
        return userId + "-" + @class
      }
    }
}
```

So what I don't understand is why the {action} component of the route registered second is not being associated with the correct method.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: could you share how your actions 'register' and 'details' look like?

Comment: I have added the class to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routing in ASP.NET Web API works in three steps:

1. Matching the URI to a route template.
2. Selecting a controller.
3. Selecting an action.

The framework selects the first route in the route table that matches the URI, there is no "second guessing" in case when 2nd or 3rd step fails - just 404. In your case both URI are always matching the first route so the second is never used.

For further analysis let's assume that the first route is:

`api/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{key}`

And you call it with following URI:

`http://<domain>/api/users/enrolments/a123/b456/`

In order to choose action framework is checking three things:

- The HTTP method of the request.
- The `{action}` placeholder in the route template, if present.
- The parameters of the actions on the controller.

In this case the `{action}` part will be resolved correctly to `enrolments`, but framework will be looking for `Enrolments` method with `userId` and `key` parameters. Your method has a `class` parameter which is no match. This will result in 404.

To avoid the issue you have to make more specific routes (like you did) or unify parameters names.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand now. I will try out a few different combinations of routes and method signatures to make sure I've got it.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to define the one route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "TestApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{key}"
);
```

Then change your controller methods to the following:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Register(string userId, string key)
{
  return userId + "-" + key;
}

[HttpGet]
public string Details(string userId, string key)
{
  return userId + "-" + key
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand why that would work. But I don't want to change the names of my parameters, I want them to reflect the actual uses.