# Custom route with action in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my `RouteConfig` I have:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

  routes.MapRoute("ApiController", "api/{controller}");

  routes.MapRoute("ApiControllerAndIntegerId", "api/{controller}/{id}", null, new { id = @"^\d+$" });

  routes.MapRoute("ApiControllerActions", "api/{controller}/{action}");
}
```

I then have a `LookupController`.

```
public class LookupsController : ApiController
{
  public string Get()
  {
    return "Default Get";
  }
  // /api/lookups/custom
  [ActionName("custom")]
  public string CustomLookup()
  {
    return "Hello, World";
  }
}
```

If I navigate to `/api/lookups/custom` I still get `Default Get` instead of `Hello, World`. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**

I have tried the different variants of `MapHttpRoute` and `MapRoute`. Neither seem to work.

Comment: For starters you should be using `MapHttpRoute` as this is for Web API routes, `MapRoute` is for ASP.NET MVC. Than try changing the route ordering (most specific route first) and you might just get what you want.

Comment: @tpeczek Following from a training video I am watching, the trainer does `File > New > MVC 4 Web Application > Web API` and `MapRoute` is the default within the `RoutesConfig`. Is this wrong?

Comment: This template is using both ASP.NET MVC (for the presentation layer) and ASP.NET Web API (for the API layer) so you are seeing both methods. In fact those are two seperate technologies. Which is bringing me to my next question. From which namespace you are using `ActionNameAttribute`? It should be `System.Web.Http` for Web API (but ASP.NET MVC has its own version in `System.Web.Mvc` namespace). And remember about the route order, read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553620/route-not-recognised-in-mvc-4-webapi/15566763#15566763

Comment: @tpeczek `ActionNameAttribute` is coming from `System.Web.Http` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong config route for Web Api, it should be [`MapHttpRoute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httproutecollectionextensions.maphttproute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) instead of `MapRoute`:

```
var configuration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

     configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "CustomizedApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );

        configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Please note that: put the route `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` on top of `"api/{controller}/{id}"`

Also, mark `[HttpGet]` in your `CustomLookup` to support GET method for this action:

```
// /api/lookups/get
public string Get()
{
    return "Default Get";
}

// /api/lookups/custom
[ActionName("custom")]
[HttpGet]
public string CustomLookup()
{
    return "Hello, World";
}
```

it will work

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have updated my question. I have tried both varients

Comment: @LukeHennerley: put `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` on top of route

Comment: Still doesn't work, unfortunatly. Doesn't seem to be registering the routes? What is `configuration` in this case?

Comment: Thanks again, however now I get the following exception: `Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
System.String Get() on type CodeCamper.Web.Controllers.LookupsController
System.String CustomLookup() on type CodeCamper.Web.Controllers.LookupsController`

Comment: @LukeHennerley: that's weird, I have made it work by hand, could you update your question to reflection what you are doing? and which url you get this eception

Comment: @LukeHennerley: for `Get` method, you need to do explicitly: `/api/lookups/get`

Comment: I am entering `/api/lookups/custom` so should see `Hello, World` in this case, I am also mapping the routes the same way as your answer.

Comment: This works... The tutorial I was following was telling me to use `RoutesConfig`, if I move the routes to the `WebApiConfig` it works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

MVC Routes are checked in the order you define them. You're having trouble with `/api/lookups/custom`, which is supposed to hit `"api/{controller}/{action}"`. However, before that you have `"api/{controller}/{id}"` and `"api/{controller}"`, so it looks like one of those is catching it. My guess would be that it's trying to parse "custom" as `{id}` in the first of those two. I notice you're not specifying default controllers or actions in your routes; it's possible you took them out before posting to take less space, but if you haven't specified defaults I recommend you do so - whether or not it's capable of picking its own defaults, it can be useful to *know* what your program's "I don't know what to do" behaviour is.

Reverse the order you're specifying those three routes in. When in doubt, put your longest and most specific routes up top, and then get gradually more vague. Putting more generic routes up top tends to result in those routes catching things that should have gone to more specific route definitions further down.

Comment: I don't have a default route, the tutorial I am following specifically said to remove them for some reason. I understand the routing a lot more thanks to this post, so +1. I have followed the post below, which more or less translates your answer to code and I still have the same problem.

Comment: I didn't say default route - I said to add default values for your specific routes. Your routes contain things like `{controller}` but you never specify default values for them. What happens when you put the `"ApiControllerActions"` route first?

Comment: Ah right! When that is first, it still loads `DefaultGet`... :(